# Adding a Space after three digits using regex Python RE

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I have a text with value : *+91 1244567* and I want to add a space after 124 hence expected result would become : *+91 124 4567*

**NOTE : input can be any number with given format.**

I want to perform this operation using regular expressions in python 3.6

thanks in advance !

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Has nothing to do with `nltk` too ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> print(re.sub(r"(\d{3})", r"\1 ", "+91 1244567", count=1))
+91 124 4567
>>>
```

This replaces only the first (`count=1`) three digits with themselves (`\1`, a backreference to the first capture group) plus a space.

Comment: Moreover, it doesn't produce expected output when country code is more than 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of these regex tricks

- `\d` digits
- `?` optional
- regex groups
- regex subtitution

Using the regex:

```
(\+\d{2})\s?(\d{3})\s?(\d{4})
```

- `(\+\d{2})` : The first group finds a substring that starts with a `+` character followed by 2 digits.
- `\s?`: An optional space between the first and second group
- `(\d{3})` : The 2nd group finds a substring that contains 3 digits.
- `\s?`: An optional space between the second and third group
- `(\d{4})` : The 3rd group finds a substring that contains 4 digits.

Code:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile("(\+\d{2})\s?(\d{3})\s?(\d{4})")
>>> num = "+91 1244567"

>>> pattern.search(num).group(1)
'+91'
>>> pattern.search(num).group(2)
'124'
>>> pattern.search(num).group(3)
'4567'
```

And make use of `re.sub` to enforce the optional spaces in your regex to become complusory spaces:

```
>>> re.sub(pattern, r'\1 \2 \3', num)
'+91 124 4567'
```